# what is Stochastic Reward Net model(SRN Model)?

Tags: uml

I can't find anywhere else. please give me the Description of Stochastic Reward Net model and the difference between UML & SRN model.

Answer (score 2):

[Stochastic Reward Networks](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2532398_Stochastic_Reward_Nets_for_Reliability_Prediction) (SRN) use [Petri nets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petri_net) for what they are trying to achieve. UML's state diagrams also base on Petri nets. The relation between SRN and UML is (at best) like between a rocket and a train. Both are used to transport people.